# PerformanceCounter category and counter confusion

Tags: c#, .net, performancecounter

I am trying to determine the number of threads my process is using in a performance API I've been writing. I know I can use the `Process.GetCurrentProcess.Threads` collection, but I've been trying to use the `PerformanceCounter` for all of the different metrics we want to monitor.

I've been able to get the CPU processing time using the following counter:

```
this.counter = new PerformanceCounter();
counter.CategoryName = "Processor";
counter.CounterName = "% processor Time";
counter.InstanceName = "_Total";
```

Now I would like to track the Thread Count for the current Process. I did some reading and identified the `CategoryName` as *Thread* from an [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.categoryname(v=vs.100).aspx):

> Although your system makes many more counter categories available, the categories that you will probably interact with most frequently are the Cache, Memory, Objects, PhysicalDisk, Process, Processor, Server, System, and **Thread** categories.

However when I use the `Thread` value as a Category, I receive the following `InvalidOperationException`:

> Could not locate Performance Counter with specified category name 'Thread', counter name 'Thread Count'

So I changed the category to Process and ran with this code:

```
this.counter = new PerformanceCounter();
counter.CategoryName = "Process";
counter.CounterName = "Thread Count";
counter.InstanceName = "_Total";
```

This is giving me values north of 2,000, and in some cases I get a fractional value which is weird, considering you either have a Thread or you don't. Not some percentage of one. When I use `Process.GetCurrentProcess.Threads` I see that I've got 15 running while using the counter, so the 2,000+ number is way off. What am I doing wrong?

I'm using the Performance Monitor to identify the available Counters and trying to build out one class per counter, for a lot of those counters. I have an interface, `IMetric`, that I want to implement a dozen or so counters behind. Any guidance on how I can determine what `CategoryName` I should be using when I identify the Counter I want would be great. It seems using the Category the counters are grouped under in `perfmon` isn't picked up when I try to use it, neither are the categories I try to use from the MSDN article. All of the metrics would be for the currently running process, so should my `CategoryName` always just be *Process*?

**Edit**

When I use the *Thread Count* Counter in perfmon, I see roughly the right number of threads (albeit the fractional number still seems weird). Why is it when I use this Counter I see 2,000+? If I change the `InstanceName` to `Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName` I see a range from 28 to 30, which doesn't match the average value I'm given by perfmon. It seems like a much more realistic number though. It still doesn't match `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads` and I'm not sure if it should or not.

[image]

Comment: When you use "_Total" then you count all of threads used by all of the processes, 2000 is not unusual of course.  Fractional values for Perfmon's average is not unusual either, happens when it divides to calculate the average.  You don't get the average in your program, 28-30 is covered by the graph.

Comment: When I replace *_Total* with `Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName` I see 9 threads, but `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count` shows me 35. Which value should I use as my trusted value?

Comment: You'll have to roll a die if you don't tell us exactly *when* you observed these values, given that neither value is a drastic mismatch from the graph.  Get another opinion from the debugger.  Enable unmanaged debugging and use the Debug > Windows > Threads debugger window.

Comment: It looks like 9 is the right number, thanks!